# Debian 11, Failed to start GNOME display manager

Tags: debian, boot, grub, gdm

I have been using my usual Debian 11 installation then I launched a command of `systemctl reboot`, after reboot I have got a black screen which stayed for around 30 seconds before the `grub` screen appeared, then after selecting the os I get an output that looks like so...

```
[FAILED] to start Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown
See 'systemctl status systemd-update-utmp.service' for details.
```

then after a few successful lines it tries to start `gdm` then stops and fails then it repeats till it reaches a `plymouth terminate` and stays like this unless I to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

After logging in I ran `systemctl status systemd-update-utmp.service`
and this is the output that I recieved

```
. systemd-update-utmp.service - UPDATE UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-update-utmp.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-02-08 14:30:01 EET; 8min  ago
     Docs: man:systemd-update-utmp.service
           man:utmp(5)
   Process: 818 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-update-utmp reboot (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Main PID: 818 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     CPU: 5ms

Feb 08 14:30:01 D20 systemd[1]: Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
Feb 08 14:30:01 D20 systemd-update-utmp[818]: Failed to write utmp record: No space left on device
Feb 08 14:30:01 D20 systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 08 14:30:01 D20 systemd[1]: systemd-update-utmp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 08 14:30:01 D20 systemd[1]: Failed to start Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
```

and when I run `systemctl status gdm.service` the output I recieve is...

```
. gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-02-08 14:31:53 EET; 19min ago
  Process: 1292 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      CPU: 5ms

Feb 08 14:31:53 D20 systemd[1]: gdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5
Feb 08 14:31:53 D20 systemd[1]: Stopped GNOME Display Manager.
Feb 08 14:31:53 D20 systemd[1]: gdm.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 08 14:31:53 D20 systemd[1]: gdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 08 14:31:53 D20 systemd[1]: Failed to start GNOME Display Manager.
Feb 08 14:31:53 D20 systemd[1]: gdm.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
```

I am a beginner at linux (and asking questions) I could not find this problem replicated anywhere, please help me or at least clarify any ways I can improve this question.

Edit:

- I have tried to add `nouveax.modeset=0` to `grub` and still same problem occurs.
- I have ran `df` and found out that `/dev/mapper/D20--vg-root` which is mounted on **/** is **100% used**.

Comment: Welcome, as the root filesystem is full it's likely the cause of the OS malfunction.

Comment: Thank you for editing and commenting, will look into it right now and post if I reached a solution.

Answer (score 0):

### My solution

*Following the edits above* I continued to try
and find a way in order to free up my root filesystem.
Running the command given by [mickael's comment here](https://askubuntu.com/a/885214/1501676%20.) Resulted in finding out that most of the storage is located in /var/logs, I went in and deleted all files (leaving the folders) which successfully made me boot into the gui successfully, but, **I do not recommend you to fully delete the log files, try and read them and find the repeating errors to solve them, then the problem will solve itself, also you might consider to use something like `logrotate`, which will help of continously trimming the logs and old deprecated ones.**